# Multiple Image Sliders 1 single Page with example

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build an multiple image slider and the problem is I cant show booth sliders at same time.

I extract the slider from [CodePen](http://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf)

There is an example page with 2 sliders [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/nL2SZ/).

```
 <ul class="slides">
   <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
     <li class="slide-container">
       <div class="slide">
(....)
</ul>     

 <ul class="slides">
   <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
     <li class="slide-container">
       <div class="slide">
(....)
</ul>
```

If someone could help me was perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1) You need each slider's `radio` elements to be unique (e.g. both cannot be `radio-btn`)

2) Each image (1-6) in each slider shares the same `id`, which is invalid as an `id` should only be used ONCE per page (e.g. in each of your sliders, your first image has `id="img-1"`).

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nL2SZ/1/) for corrects to your code.  Notice how both sliders now work?!  Woot woot!

All I did is add `-1` to the first slider's elements, and `-2` to all of the second slider's elements!

**E.G. FIRST SLIDER**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" checked />
```

BECAME

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn-1" id="img-1-2" checked />
```

**E.G. SECOND SLIDER**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" checked />
```

BECAME

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn-2" id="img-2-5" checked />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! My first thought was change the class slider but without success